# How to parse string containing dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here it's my json.

```
"{'item1': 1, 'item2': 2, 'item3': 3, 'item4': 4}"
```

above dict is in string format

now I want to parse these data in following format

```
item1 = 1
item2 = 2
item3 = 3
item4 = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
from ast import literal_eval

for k,v in literal_eval("{'item1': 1, 'item2': 2, 'item3': 3, 'item4': 4}").items():
    print("{} == {}".format(k,v))
```

**Output**

```
item3 == 3
item2 == 2
item1 == 1
item4 == 4
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
In [19]: value = "{'item1':1, 'item2':2, 'item3', 'item4':4}"

In [20]: value = ast.literal_eval(value)

In [21]: for i in value:
    print i + "=" + str(value[i])



 ....     
item2=2
item3=3
item1=1
item4=4
```